# Error while using Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, opengl, swift-package-manager

I'm following [this](http://www.swiftgl.org/learn/01-hello-window.html) tutorial on using OpenGL in Swift. It apparently depends on some GitHub Repo for GLFW and uses a Package.swift file to build it into your executable.  Sadly, while running the instructed build command `swift build -Xcc -I/usr/local/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib` I get the following error:

> error: Empty manifest file is not supported anymore. Use `swift package init` to autogenerate.

When I run the suggested init command, I get:

> error: a manifest file already exists in this directory

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is written for Swift version 2, and it’s been outdated for some time. The only reason you need the library in that repository is because it defines some OpenGL function loaders necessary to make your program link properly. I currently use a patched version of that `SGLOpenGL` library that I hacked to make it compile under Swift 3. I believe this is the only way currently to use OpenGL with Swift. You will have to correct the Swift `UnsafePointer`s and rewrite the function parameter lists to use (or remove) named arguments, among other things, as Swift 3 was a source-breaking release. The compiler will generally tell you what you have to do, it’s just a lot of tedious work.

Note that you don’t need any of Turnbull’s other libraries to use OpenGL with Swift. You can easily (“easily”) write your own implementations of the `Math` functions for the quaternions, vectors, matrices, camera frusta, etc. Google is your friend, as most of these routines are well-studied problems in computer graphics, and there is a great deal of pseudocode and C++ implementations on the web to help you get started.

The `Image` PNG library is non-trivial to replace, but luckily there already exists a native Swift PNG decoder [`MaxPNG`](https://github.com/kelvin13/maxpng)<sup>†</sup> designed to work with graphics frameworks.

Good luck!!!

<sup>†</sup> (*Disclosure, I am the author of `MaxPNG`; I wrote it because I was in the exact same position as you a few months ago.*)

Comment: What about GLKit? Isn't that a way to use Swift 3 and OpenGL?  I'm not sure I understand your answer however insofar as there is a comment on that Repo's Issue's that says you can checkout a new tag and it should work.  Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with SPM.  Ultimately I plan on using GLKit as I'm writing an iOS app.  But I am amazed at the virtual non-existence of any working tutorials for the dominant graphics API on the planet.

Comment: @AlexBollbach GLKit is Apple-proprietary. As for the lack of Apple-independent tutorials,  I am equally shocked as you, having worked on Swift GPU programming for quite some time. It is probably due to the fact that Swift was only recently open sourced, and the Linux user base is still very small (though rapidly growing). Writing Linux Swift GL tutorials is on my bucket list, but if you need help feel free to ping me

Comment: @AlexBollbach same with releasing a proper Swift OpenGL function loader, as the patched one i’m using right now is kind of hacked together

Comment: how can I ping you?

Comment: @AlexBollbach use [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if you want, though preferably, post your questions on here instead so others can learn as well. The [`swift-users`](https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-users) mailing list is also a good venue